# Azure php Error Deployment from local git - using tutorial

Tags: php, azure

so I'm new to azure deployment and I try my best to use the microsoft documentation tutorial
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-php-mysql-app?pivots=platform-windows

everything is fine until "Deploy to Azure" Step in :

> git push azure main

```
remote:   [ErrorException]
remote:   Trying to access array offset on value of type null
remote: An error has occurred during web site deployment.
remote:
remote: composer failed
remote:
remote:
remote: Error - Changes committed to remote repository but deployment to website failed.
To https://phpmysqldemogs.scm.azurewebsites.net/phpMysqlDemoGS.git
```

The log detail from Deployment Center > Logs show I have failed commit with detail log

```
Command: bash deploy.sh
 Creating app_offline.htm
 KuduSync.NET from: 'C:\home\site\repository' to: 'C:\home\site\wwwroot'
 Deleting app_offline.htm
 Running composer install
    
                                                           
   [ErrorException]                                     
   Trying to access array offset on value of type null  
                                                           
 An error has occurred during web site deployment.
    
 composer failed
 [ErrorException]                                     \r\n  Trying to access array offset on value of type null\r\nC:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\95.30831.5373\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd bash deploy.sh
```

I tried to push again, it says "already up to date"

I tried to clone  repo from azure, do composer install then php artisan serve ... it worked locally, so I assume that the problem is in deployment configuration. Can anyone help the production problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that any message that starts with `remote:` is not coming *from Git*. Instead, Git is just the messenger. Don't shoot (or even bother tagging) the messenger. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error `Error - Changes committed to remote repository but deployment to website failed.` occurs when you push a local branch that doesn't match the app deployment branch on 'azure'.

- To resolve this error, Verify that the current branch is `master`. To change the default branch, use `DEPLOYMENT_BRANCH` application setting (refer to [Change deployment branch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-local-git?tabs=cli#change-deployment-branch)).

You are also getting `Trying to access array offset on value of type null` error and that is failing composer.

- To resolve this error, you need to updater the composer.

```
composer update
```

OR

```
php composer.phar update
```

[image]

You can refer to [Troubleshoot deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-local-git?tabs=cli#troubleshoot-deployment) and [Error "Trying to access array offset on value of type null"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60188713/error-trying-to-access-array-offset-on-value-of-type-null-laravel-5-8-26-php-7)