# how to access array offset on value of type null

Tags: php, html

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\MINI PROJECT\CDP\presentationlayer\doctor\index2.php on line 38

The error above is what i get when i click on the doctor's info on my website and it is same for 41,44,47,50.

below is the code;

```
<?php include ('../../datalayer/server.php'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Doctor</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="style3.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alfa+Slab+One&family=Open+Sans:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<header>
    <h1 >Doctor<span>Patient</span></h1>
        <nav>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="index2.php">MyInfo</a></li>
            <li><a href="doctorapp.php">My Appointments</a></li>
            <li><a href=" searchpatient.php">Search Patient</a></li>
            <li><a href="add.php">Add Description</a></li>
            <li><a href="../../consultant/consultant.html">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
<body>

    <div class="header">
    <h2>My Information</h2>
</div>
<form method="post" action="index2.php" class="info">
<div class="Dcontent">


    <label>ID: <?php echo "" .isset($_SESSION['DoctorID']);?></label>

           <br>
           <br>
          38. <label> Email : <?php echo $colD['email']; ?></label>
                   <br>
           <br>
          41. <label> Name : <?php echo $colD['Doctorname']; ?></label>
                   <br>
           <br>
          44. <label> Address : <?php echo $colD['Address']; ?></label>
                   <br>
           <br>
          47. <label> Contact Number : <?php echo $colD['ContactNumber']; ?></label>
                   <br>
           <br>
          50. <label> Specialized In : <?php echo $colD['category']; ?></label>
                   <br>
           <br>

  </div>
</form>
<!--<div class="footer">
    <div id="copyright"><small>© 2021 Kwame Nkrumah University of Science & Technology.</small></div>
</div>-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: and line 38 in index2.php is...? You've provided a totally irrelevant code from a wrong file..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to access array offset on value of type null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59322150/trying-to-access-array-offset-on-value-of-type-null)

Comment: 38. <label> Email : <?php echo $colD['email']; ?></label>

Comment: looks like your `$colD` variable is null

Comment: Please. null as in?

Comment: Obviously, you may want to define variable `$colD`, to begin with ... before being able to access any element within that `array`... `$colD = [];` would at least give you an array (which has no elements). Based on the footer notice ...is this your homework?

Comment: $userprofile=isset($_SESSION['UserID']);
$query="SELECT * FROM patients WHERE UserID=('$userprofile')";
 $result= mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
 $col= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
The code above is what i wrote in the php file