# Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:/...... on line 40

Tags: php, html, mysql, reference, return-value

Please help me, i am new to flutter and i have the above problemon my PHP code, see example or line that is being complained about;

```
    <ul>
            <li><a href="function/logout.php"><i class="icon-off icon-white"></i>logout</a></li>
            <li>Welcome:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#profile" href  data-toggle="modal"><i class="icon-user icon-white"></i><?php echo $fetch['firstname']; ?>&nbsp;<?php echo $fetch['lastname'];?></a></li>
        </ul>
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: There are some array index of $fetch that doesn't exist. Make a <?php var_dump($fetch);?>  and check which index is missing

Comment: Does this answer your question [Trying to access array offset on value of type null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59322150/trying-to-access-array-offset-on-value-of-type-null) ?